# Is it possible for two processes to access the webcam at the same time?

Tags: video, webcam

I would like to try using Cheese in Google+ Hangouts, and similar configurations, and I would like to know if it is possible for the webcam to be used by two processes to have access to the webcam at the same time. I have not tried it as yet, but before I do, I figured I would ask.

So, is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I just tried. Interesting results.

I have got skype and cheese and webcam toy and hangouts (which all do work) and tried them together.

Results:

You can't use the same webcam on 2 things at once.

Cheese (Working) + Webcam Toy (Not working) + Skype (Small, top right. Not working).

[image]

You can use 2 webcams on 2 things though. (Cheese + Webcam Toy).

[image]

Hangouts (Not working) + Cheese (Working)

[image]

Hangouts (Working on it's own).

[image]

Cheese broken when I opened Hangouts first. It did the same with the others, but my internet is too slow to upload every single screenshot (and I doubt you'd appreciate 30+ screenshots)...

[image]

I even tried making a symbolic link to `/dev/video0` and saving it in `/dev` as `video2`. That didn't work.

I also can't run 2 cheese processes at once.

If you had to, I would advise making it full screen and doing 2 screen recordings. I doubt that would work for what you want though.

Comment: Thanks! This is concise and tells me what I need to know. Nice garden btw! The bounty will be awarded when the timeout expires (21 hrs to go). Then I will delete this comment.

Comment: @Mew That was my last attempt at getting it to work :)

Comment: @Tim The next answer is exactly what you're looking for if you came here because you need a way to do that.

Comment: @impinball nope, just found it an interesting question!

Answer (score 26):

## Happily, now, YES!

There is currently a project on GitHub that can show not only two, but an infinite (limited only by system capacity) number of video devices from a single source.

The project is called [`v4l2loopback`](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback). (Check the link and scroll down to view the README for instructions.)

You can install `v4l2loopback` by cloning its GitHub and running these commands:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback.git
$ cd v4l2loopback
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

### Examples

For samples on how to use it with GStreamer, FFmpeg, MPlayer, and Skype, check their small [wiki](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/wiki). Hopefully you could find the right settings to fit your needs.

Enjoy tweaking around!

Comment: Virtual devices is one of the areas where Linux (and *nix, for that matter) shines. It is more complicated on Windows to even write a basic `tee` utility that doesn't wait for `stdin` to finish feeding it stuff. I wouldn't be surprised if this actually uses a binary equivalent to `tee` with more scalable support under the hood.

Comment: Whilst this does answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include parts of the link here, and provide the link for reference, so that we have some examples - e.g. make 2 devices from 1. What are the options for that? And is it possible (as said in the OP's requirements) to use with Google hangouts? I also just tested it with Skype and it doesn't seem to work. We are now version 4.3 not 4.0...

Comment: I'll have to check this out when my other system gets back. I'll probably give an additional bounty.

Comment: This is now actually part of ubuntu - no need for git.

Comment: Indeed, this is now packaged for Ubuntu / Debian as v4l2loopback-utils
No need to self compile this

Answer (score 10):

Since there is no answer using `ffmpeg`, this is it.

---

### Explanation

While `v4l2loopback` creates virtual video devices, they are not associated with anything by default. To make them useful, you have to send streams to them via external applications such as `ffmpeg`.

First load the module

```bsh
$ sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 video_nr=5 #creates `/dev/video5`
```

and then send your webcam's input to the virtual device.

```bsh
$ ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f v4l2 -codec:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p /dev/video5
```

Now `/dev/video5` works as a pseudo-webcam. Note, unlike a physical webcam, a single virtual video device can be accessed from multiple applications simultaneously. Thus, in this case, you don't have to create many virtual devices.

I wrote a script to wrap these steps: [*v4l2_webcam - GitHub*](https://github.com/your-diary/v4l2_webcam).

---

### Application

You can send any (raw) video to a virtual video device. This means, for example, it is possible to use a complicatedly mixed video by [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) as a camera input to a Web meeting (e.g. Skype, Zoom, etc.).

Here is a relatively complex but very practical example:

#### Structure

[image: example_structure]

#### Result

[image: example_result]

Comment: This answer worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Based on @The Eye answer

I first installed gstreamer packages on Ubuntu 18.04
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html

```
$ git clone https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback.git
$ cd v4l2loopback
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

I got warning message as here on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/139 (but it didn't prevent me from loading v4l2loopback driver)

```
$ sudo depmod -a
```

I just have 1 webcam on my laptop /dev/video0 and I wanted to get 2 streams from the same hardware. Based on https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/blob/master/README.md

```
$ modprobe v4l2loopback devices=2
```

There should now be `/dev/video1` and `/dev/video2` created assuming `/dev/video0` was the only video device.

Now I run the following in one terminal window

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! tee name=t ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1 t. ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2
```

I open 2 more tabs

In the first tab

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
```

In the second tab

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
```

Now one should see 2 video streams

**UPDATE**

Even if I use the same `/dev/video1` device multiple times it all gives me that many stream. example.

In the first tab

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
```

In the second tab

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
```

In the third tab

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
```

gives me three streams.

Comment: BTW if one's webcam has audio then filter audio devices using the command `pactl list | grep -A2 'Source #'` then use that device in the following pipeline (can run multiple instances of pipeline too) `gst-launch-1.0 pulsesrc device=alsa_input.<name of device> ! autoaudiosink`

Comment: This works much better than the FFmpeg solution as I couldn't get FFmpeg to copy h264 without decoding it which resulted in it always using the CPU even when no one was listening

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no with a maybe... The Library, "Video 4 Linux" detects whether a device is being used, and will not initiate. However; if you wish to download libv4l-dev and edit it manually, you can edit the code to get rid of this check and then just recompile it. I imagine you could get this to work, but it would be extremely unstable. May be worth checking out though.

TLDR: Anything is possible if you are a programmer with some elbow grease handy. Don't want to go that far? Then no; its not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I have success using OBS Open Broadcast Software after the following steps:

1. Install video4linux loopback device, v4l2loopback as suggested by others. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and had to install a newer version as suggested [here](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink/issues/30)
2. Install OBS. Again I had to install a newer version and ffmpeg as per [these instructions](https://itsubuntu.com/install-obs-in-linux-operating-system/).
3. Install OBS-v4lsink. Go [here](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink/releases) and download and install the `.deb` file, version 0.1.0 was the only deb file there.
4. Start v4l2loopback:

   ```
    sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
   ```
5. In OBS and select a source. Under "sources" click on "+", give your new layer a name, select your (real) webcam.
6. In OBS select a sink. In the top menu go to Tools > v42lsink, select the virtual webcam (`/dev/videoX`, with `X` being the highest number available), click start.
7. In your applications, select the virtual webcam. I had Zoom and Discord both using the same new virtual webcam and was also able to record from the camera using OBS.

Comment: [obs-v4l2sink](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink) has been archived on 2021.